# Solve the following recurrence equation exactly:

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the following recurrence equation exactly:

$$T(1) = a, T(2) = b$$
$$T(n) = T(n–2) + c$$

I'm not sure what this is asking, can someone provide some insight?

Comment: Find $T(n)$ in terms of $n$, $a$, $b$, $c$, but not in terms of $T$ itself.

Comment: Can you write the first couple terms out?  For example, what does $T(3)$ evaluate to?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are to find a function $f(n,a,b,c)$ such that $T(n) = f(n,a,b,c)$. [This article on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Theorem) has several techniques that will help you to find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If we take one case as $n$ is an even number, then let $n=2k$.

$$\begin{align}
T(n) = T(2k) =& T(2k-2)+c\\
=& [T(2k-2-2) + c] + c\\
=& \{[T(2k-2-2-2) + c] + c\}+c\\
=& T(2k-3\times2) + 3c\\
=& T(2k-h\times2) + hc &\text{by induction}\\
\end{align}$$

Now, if you take an appropriate $h$ such that $T(2k-2h$) is a known value, then you can find a close form for $T(n)$, for even $n$.

The other case is similar.

Answer (score 0):

$T(n)$ is in form of $dn + e<br/>$

$$T(1) = a = d + e$$
$$T(2) = b = 2d + e$$
$$d = b - a$$
$$T(n+1) = dn + d + 2  = T(n-1) +c = dn - d + e + c$$
$$2d = c$$
$2a - b = e$$
$$T(3) = 3d + e = T(1) + c = a + c$
$$T(4) = 4d + e = T(2) + c = b + c$$
$$T(n) = nd + e = n(b-a) + 2a - b$$